# Why is my application crashing on debug with Application stopped?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, debugging, build.gradle

The build runs successfully but closes with notification "Application stopped" on my monitoring device. I have the following errors in my logcat:

```
2020-05-07 08:57:47.729 22899-22899/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2020-05-07 08:57:54.781 22899-22899/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
2020-05-07 08:57:54.781 22899-22899/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-07 08:57:54.930 22899-22925/net.groupkse.indupendo E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg"
2020-05-07 08:57:55.355 22899-22972/net.groupkse.indupendo E/libARC: item map does not been created yet!
2020-05-07 08:57:55.395 22899-22899/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-07 08:57:55.412 22899-22899/net.groupkse.indupendo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.groupkse.indupendo, PID: 22899
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 actions=3 vis=PRIVATE)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

Where could the issue be?

Comment: Attach error of logcat please

Comment: _"Where could the issue be?"_ The crash log clearly says it is in a `startForeground()` call for your Service and more specifically the problem is the notification channel which is null. You need to look at the Android documentation for Foreground Services as the exact code needed to create the notification changed in a recent Android version. It was in Android 9 perhaps(?)

Comment: Those in the code section are the only errors in my logcat MohammadMoeinGolchin.

Comment: Ah, it was already in Android 8: [Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: Okay Mohammad let me look at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you registered your notification channel first by using `createNotificationChannel`? Example code below, taken from the [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#java):

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```